# ROS Diamondback on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: ros, 64bit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

using Ubuntu 64 Bit instead of Ubuntu 32 Bit would give some benefits (e.g. you can use more then 8 cpu cores). Is it possible to run Diamondback under Ubuntu 64 Bit? Do most stacks (e.g. ccny_vision) work under 64 Bit Ubuntu? If it is possible at all: Does anyone have experience if it is possible to use Ros and Ubuntu 64 Bit without having much trouble?

Regards,
Bastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12283/ros-diamondback-on-ubuntu-64-bit/) by [Bastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1451/bastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been running ROS on various 64-bit Ubuntu systems for years without any problems. Diamondback (or Electric, or C-turtle) will work fine on any supported Ubuntu version. All the build tests are run continuously in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 64bit is the default development environment at Willow Garage.  At this point things are more likely to fail on 32 bit than 64 bit.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3